# Source code of Google baked containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Where can I find the source code of Google baked containers like this zookeeper one?:

```
gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-zookeeper
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the container maintainer. for the provided example:

```
https://github.com/kow3ns/kubernetes-zookeeper
```

More information for finding related dockerfiles:

I just googled: `gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-zookeeper dockerfile`